# segmentation fault double pointer

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, double-pointer

I'm having a segmentation fault on the following code and i really don't see what i missed, the aim of this code is to retrieve lines of a .csv and put them in a 2D array created with a double pointer.

The seg fault is situated at the last assigment of plaintexts[i][j] for the 1st line of the csv file.

Your help would be much appreciated (on this problem since yesterday...)

```
int main(){


int n=48; //nbers of columns in csv file
int m=60; //nbers of lines in csv file


int cpt,i,j;
cpt=0;
i=0;
FILE *fp;
char *token;
const char s[2] = ",";

unsigned char **plaintexts;
plaintexts = malloc(sizeof(*plaintexts) * m);

char *str=malloc(sizeof(char)*15*n); //maximum 15 char per box
fp = fopen("aes_traces.csv","r");




while(fgets(str,15*n,fp)!=NULL){

    plaintexts[i] = malloc(sizeof(*plaintexts[i]) * n);
    token = strtok(str,s);
    j=0;
    while(token != NULL){
        printf("%s\n", token);
        token = strtok(NULL,s);
        plaintexts[i][j]=(unsigned char) (*token);

        j++;

    }

    i++;
    free(str);
    free(token);
}


fclose(fp);

}
```

Comment: What are the values of `i`, `j`, `n`, and `token` when the fault occurs?

Comment: Can you run valgrind against your program and post the results here ?

Comment: If you want an array of lines when each line is an array of tokens, you need a 3D array as each token is an array of characters.

Comment: Furhermore, your inner loop structure is wrong. When you say `while (token != NULL)`, you can use `*token` before you assign to `token` in the loop body, but not after. You also lose the very first token. Think how to fx both problems at once by one simple change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while(token != NULL){
    printf("%s\n", token);
    token = strtok(NULL,s); // A
    plaintexts[i][j]=(unsigned char) (*token); // B

    j++;
}
```

If this loop runs at least once, it will end in a segfault. Why? The loop can't terminate until `token` is set to NULL in the line I marked `A` and then dereferenced in the line I marked `B`. Dereferencing a NULL will cause a segfault.

Comment: Thanks David, it solve this segmentation problem (i inverted line A and B) but i have another one now for i=1 when i do a malloc on plaintexts[i]...

Comment: You need to learn how to troubleshoot. Learn how to identify precisely which line of code causes the segfault and what that line of code is doing wrong with it does segfault.

Comment: I agree with you David, it's just that this problem should be a detail on a much bigger project i have to do for school and i'm trying to solve it as fast as possible, i think i don't get how double pointers and 2d arrays works, i have to review it

Comment: Try explaining what `free(token)` and `free(str)` are doing there. How many times do you free them? How many times do you malloc them?

Comment: Thanks ! When i removed the    'free(str)' no more Seg fault ! I don't see why though...  it just free the area pointed by str and i don't see the link with the malloc of plaintexts[i]

Comment: Use valgrind to troubleshoot. The problem could be before the call to `free`.

Comment: You don't have segfaults but you don't know whether you have built the array correctly.